# Faded text on Apple TV info view

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

When I set the `externalMetadata` on my `AVPlayerItem` and load it into the player of `AVPlayerViewController` it loads my metadata in the Info but the text is faded http://drop.lyokotech.com/image/0F0V2W1c431A/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-10%20at%2014.30.03.png

Any idea why this would happen?  This is how I am loading it (From the root view controller)

```
     func getMetadata() -> [AVMetadataItem] {
        var items = [AVMetadataItem]()

        func createMetaDataItem(key: String, value: String) -> AVMetadataItem {
            let data = AVMutableMetadataItem()
            data.key = key
            data.value = value
            data.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon
            data.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

            return data
        }

        let title = createMetaDataItem(AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle, value: "SOME TITLE")
        let description = createMetaDataItem(AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription, value: "SOME DESCRIPTION")


        items.append(title)
        items.append(description)

        return items
    }
    let metadata = getMetadata()

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("IMG_0343", ofType: "MOV") {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
        item.externalMetadata = metadata
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

        let av = AVPlayerViewController()
        av.player = player
        av.player?.play()

        presentViewController(av, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This happens whether I use a local file or a stream (HLS)

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention, it only happens in the simulator.  Can't see if it happens on device because I lack a USB-C cable

Comment: It will work fine on TVOS, I am having same issue in simulator but on real devices its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a problem in a simulator. It will work fine on a real device.